# Term for greetings that are also valedictions

Tags: terminology, linguistics, greetings, valediction

Is there a specialized term in linguistics for those words that, in a given language, can be used to say both *hello* and *goodbye*?

For instance, I've heard tell that in Hawaii the word "aloha" is used either to greet people or to bid them farewell. If I am not mistaken, the Italian word "ciao" also has this twofold functionality and I suppose that polyglots can easily come up with many more examples of this curious language phenomenon.

Thanks in advance for your learned replies!

Comment: Ciao dual meaning of "hello" and "goodbye" makes it similar to *shalom* in Hebrew, *salaam* in Arabic, *annyeong* in Korean, and *aloha* in Hawaiian. The Vietnamese word *chào* ("hello" or "goodbye"), while similar-sounding, is unrelated etymologically.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Salutation**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/salutation)

A gesture or utterance made as a greeting or acknowledgment of another’s arrival or departure

Comment: Aww. Beat me to it!

Comment: I don't know... I don't think that any salutation can be used BOTH ways.

Comment: @J.H.S. - "Aloha" is a salutation that can be used either way.  I don't know of any "English" salutations that can be, however.

Comment: @J.H.S. "Salutations" can be a greeting or a parting word...

Comment: So, it seems like the phenomenon in question occurs in the English language too. Neat!

Comment: @J.H.S. - As I said, I don't know of any actual English (not "borrowed") salutation that can be used for both "hello" and "goodbye", but if such a word were found it would be a "salutation" (as is the "borrowed" word "aloha").

Comment: It's a bit old-fashioned but salutations of the form "good morning" can be used in both ways [(reference.com).](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good+morning)